# PHP Reads wrong data

Tags: php, binaryfiles

I'm reading a binary file in PHP:

```
$File = fopen('simplefile', 'rb');
// Random stuff
fseek($File, $APosition);
for($I = 0; $I < 10; $I ++ ){
    var_dump(unpack('V', fread($File, 4)));
}
fclose($File);
```

However this does not give correct output for that position (it is giving `6357101` not `4294967295` as expected - I've checked using a hex editor).

However, this work and gives the correct values:

```
$File = fopen('simplefile', 'rb');
// Random stuff
fseek($File, $APosition);
for($I = 0; $I < 10; $I ++ ){
    fseek($File, ftell($File));  // What is this line doing?
    var_dump(unpack('V', fread($File, 4)));
}
fclose($File);
```

This however, I don't understand as surely `fseek($File, ftell($File));` does absolutely nothing? What is that line doing and how can I read the correct values without errors?

---

This segment of the file is just `0xFF` repeated several hundred times.

Comment: Can you provide a self-contained example we can confirm, for example by simulating your file using `fopen('php://memory', 'r+b')`, `fwrite($File, "\xFF\xFF...")`?

Comment: Just for completeness, what is $APosition set to?

Comment: @RiggsFolly `$APosition` can be anything, the value is taken from the file. In the case of this file it is `2048`. @deceze - I'm having difficulty in duplicating the issue outside my own code, which might just say something about the code...

Comment: Indeed it might... :-3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I set up a file of all `FF` bytes, and the loop correctly reads -1 ten times, which is 4294967295 unsigned. I can't reproduce the value you get.

The value you are getting, `6357101`, corresponds to the bytes `6D 00 61 00`. That is the characters 'ma' encoded in UTF-16, although it could also mean other things.

I think the file or the content of the file is not what you think it is, or you are reading from the wrong place.

```
fseek($File, ftell($File));  // What is this line doing?
```

It should do nothing. If it doesn't do nothing I can only speculate that perhaps the file is corrupt on disk, or your copy of PHP is borked, or your computer has gone quietly mad.

Comment: I probably shouldn't have put `6357101` in the answer as the values `fread` is producing vary across each iteration. I'm printing out the pointer location and it is where it says it should be both times, yet yielding totally different results.

Comment: @Bonzo Are you sure that nothing else is modifying the file at the same time?

Comment: Yep. There are no modifications going on. On interest, what would be the performance impact of leaving `fseek($File, ftell($File));` in? It is slightly depressing as the rest of my code is parsing the file fine.

Comment: @Bonzo Depends how many times you're running the loop (thousands? millions?) but I don't think it will affect the performance too much. It definitely shouldn't change the data though.

Answer (score -2):

If you dont use that line, that mean, you are still reading the first 4 Bytes in Loop. You need do seek.

**sometxtfile.txt**

```
aaaabbbbcccc
```

Without that line it ould be like:

This will return `aaaaaaaaaaaa`:

```
$File = fopen('sometxtfile.txt', 'rb');
echo fread($File, 4);
echo fread($File, 4);
echo fread($File, 4);
```

With that line it is like:

This will return `aaaabbbbcccc`:

```
$File = fopen('sometxtfile.txt', 'rb');
echo fread($File, 4);
fseek($File, ftell($File));
echo fread($File, 4);
fseek($File, ftell($File));
echo fread($File, 4);
fseek($File, ftell($File));
```

See PHP documentation for further info.